# Get a Label control value using its class name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have one label control as

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" Visible="false" CssClass="label1css"></asp:Label>
```

So I am assigning some value to this label control. So how I will get that assigned value by using its class name in jQuery.

Comment: Why by class name and not by the `id`? read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: from the comment asp:Label controls are rendered as span elements, so...)

HTML <s>label</s>span elements don't have a "value". If you mean the content of the <s>label</s>span element in the sense of <s>`<label>Content</label>`</s>`<span>Content</span>` then try this:

```
$(".label1css").text()
// OR
$(".label1css").html()
```

If you mean that you are going to assign a "value" attribute along the lines of <s>`<label value="whatever">`</s>`<span value="whatever">` then try:

```
$(".label1css").attr("value")
```

Note that this will not work if more than one element has that same "label1css" class - the ".label1css" selector will get all matching elements and then the `.text()` or `.html()` or `.attr()` method will get a value from the first matching element. From the name "label1css" it sounds like you *are* making the class name unique, which will work but really you should be using the id attribute for this purpose.

Comment: +1 More Info : `asp:Label` is converted to `span` on client side.

Comment: Thanks. I've made a minor edit to my answer to talk about "span" rather than "label", but really that makes no difference in how you do this particular operation. Be sure to look into what gdoron said about using the id (I had mentioned it but didn't know the asp syntax to get a client-side id, but gdoron shows that.)

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = $('.label1css').text();
```

Note that this element has an `id`. selecting by `id` is a lot more efficient.

```
var value = $('#<%=label1.ClientID%>').text(); // this is better
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var txtSelect = $('.user').text();
alert(txtSelect);
```